# How do I make a link in PHP that appears as something other than the link?

Tags: php, text, web, hyperlink

I am trying to make a link using PHP that takes me to a new website, but I don't want the actual link address to appear.  I need to display "Text here" and have that text link to www.example.com

I have a script that will make a link for me, but it displays "www.example.com" instead of "Text here".

Thanks for any help.

```
function makeURL($URL) {
$URL = eregi_replace('(((f|ht){1}tp://)[-a-zA-Z0-9@:\+.~#?&//=]+)','<a href=\\1>\\1</a>', $URL);
$URL = eregi_replace('([[:space:]()[{}])(www.[-a-zA-Z0-9@:\+.~#?&//=]+)','<a href=\\1>\\1</a>', $URL);
$URL = eregi_replace('([_\.0-9a-z-]+@([0-9a-z][0-9a-z-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,3})','<a href=\\1>\\1</a>', $URL);
return $URL;
}
```

Comment: Could you add the script to your question?

Comment: `ereg_*` functions are deprecated use `preg_*` instead

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a HTML question:

```
<a href="www.yourwebsite">Some text that is a link</a>
```

Comment: answer I was looking for, but assigned to a php variable.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As i understand you want to prevent showing link address when a user mouse over the link.

Here is the solution with jQuery

```
<a data-link="www.example.com" class="hidden-link">Text here</a>

jQuery(function($) {
    $('a.hidden-link').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        document.location.href = $(this).data('link');
    });
});
```